# NextJS with WPML

Tags: javascript, wordpress, next.js, graphql, wpml

Hello so I have a problem regarding my NextJS project.
I'm trying to change context regarding to what language i provide.
On my "nyheter.tsx" file the function work, but thats why the graphQL provide me with a where variable. like this :

```
`  query GetQueryNews($language: String!) {
    nyhet(where: { wpmlLanguage: $language }) {
      nodes {
        title
        slug
      }
    }
  }`
```

unfort the single post dosent provide me with the variables to do the same thing. Instead the translated content is more like this:
`query AllPagesQuery($slug: String!) { nyheterBy(slug: $slug) { content translated { // translated code.  translated { content } } } }`

Therefore i choose to use the the wp-json instead.
The problem I have right now is to get the correct data when I change language, right now the slug is same and the NextJS i18n is just generating a en/ in url instead of changing the language slug.

I don't know if i'm completely lost or something . But I hope you get the ide what I mean. Do you have any tips ?

[slug].tsx

```
`import { GetStaticPaths, GetStaticProps } from 'next'
import { gql } from '@apollo/client'
import client from '@/lib/apollo-client'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { getThemeSettings } from '@/graphql/Settings/themeSettings'
import { getMainMenu } from '@/graphql/Templates/mainMenu'
import Link from 'next/link'
import Image from 'next/image'

const NewsPage = ({ response }) => {
  const data = response.map((data) => data)
  return (
    <div>
      {...data.map((data, index) => {
        console.log(data)
        return (
          <div className="m-5 w-8/12" key={index}>
            <h2 className="text-4xl mb-5">{data.title.rendered}</h2>
            <div
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: data.content.rendered
              }}
            />
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export const getStaticPaths = async ({ locales }) => {
  const paths = []
  for (const locale of locales) {
    const data = await fetch(
      `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WP_URL}wp-json/wp/v2/nyheter?lang=${locale}&_fields=slug`
    )
    const slugData = await data.json()

    const localePaths = slugData.map((item) => {
      return { params: { slug: item.slug }, locale }
    })
    paths.push(...localePaths)
  }

  console.log('paths', paths)

  return {
    paths: paths,
    fallback: 'blocking'
  }
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({
  params,
  locale
}) => {
  const mainMenu = await getMainMenu()
  const ThemeSettings = await getThemeSettings()

  const data = await fetch(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_WP_URL}wp-json/wp/v2/nyheter?lang=${locale}&slug=${params.slug}&_embed`
  )
  const response = await data.json()

  console.log(params.slug)

  return {
    props: {
      params,
      response,
      mainMenu,
      locale,
      ThemeSettings: ThemeSettings?.props.ThemeSettings,
      allSettings: ThemeSettings?.props
    }
  }
}

export default NewsPage
`
```

Header.tsx

```
`import Logo from 'assets/svg/logo'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { mainMenu } from 'theme'
import { motion } from 'framer-motion'

const Header = ({ data, ThemeSettings }) => {
  const { locale: activeLocale, locales, asPath } = useRouter()
  const router = useRouter()
  const availableLocales = locales.filter(
    (locale) => locale !== activeLocale
  )

  return (
    <div className="items-center justify-between flex w-full pr-10 pl-10">
      <Link href="/">
        {ThemeSettings?.logotype ? (
          <div>
            <Image
              src={ThemeSettings.logotype?.sourceUrl}
              height="120"
              width="80"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <Logo />
          </div>
        )}
      </Link>
      <div className="flex z-50 items-center">
        {data?.map((items, index) => {
          const ifUrl = items.page ? `${items.page}` : `${items.url}`
          typeof ifUrl !== 'undefined' && null
          return (
            <motion.div
              key={index}
              initial={{ transform: 'translateY(-100px)' }}
              animate={{ transform: 'translateY(0)' }}
              transition={{ duration: 1, delay: 1.5 }}
            >
              <Link
                href={`${ifUrl}`}
                style={{ color: mainMenu.textColor }}
              >
                <span className="px-2">{items.label}</span>
              </Link>
            </motion.div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          {availableLocales.map((locale) => {
            return (
              <li key={locale}>
                <Link href={asPath} locale={locale}>
                  {locale}
                </Link>
              </li>
            )
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

export default Header
`

Tried,

- Updating slug depending on what locale lang is.
- To get the nyhetBy graphql and update content from there.